# Mercurial Queues, patch is getting auto applied

Tags: mercurial, patch, mercurial-queue

I have two patches:

- `patch1`
- `patch2`

When I apply `patch1`, that is the only thing that gets applied. When I do `hg qpop` and then do `hg qpush patch2`, for some reason `patch1` gets applied too. How can I make them independent from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--move` option for that. For example:

```
hg qpush --move patch2
```

This will apply only `patch2`, but not any patches on top of it.